# how to reduce the spacing on 2 images?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position the images better but I don't understand why it's blocking?
There are several spaces that are created...

Why are my images not aligning correctly? I would like everything to be well aligned.

Maybe I'm missing a property in the `.checkboxButtons .icon` class?

[image]

Would you please show me how to do it?

Thank you for your help and your time.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 #content {
      background: #fff;
  }
  
 #content .wrapper {
      padding-top: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  
 #content .wrapper {
      padding: 0 0 50px 0;
  }
  
 .wrapper {
      width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: aqua;
      height: 70%;
 }


#content .backgroundRed {
      float: left;
      width: 700px;
      background-color: red;
      height: 50%;
  
  }



.checkboxButtons .icon {
      top: -8px;
      float: left;
      left: -20px;
      position: relative;
      height: 27px;
      width: 25px;
      background: url("https://zupimages.net/up/21/27/ijsz.png") -60px -911px no-repeat;
}


 #content .checkboxButtons {
      float: right;
      right: -32px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: yellow;
    
}
```

```html
  <div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="backgroundRed">     
      </div>
      <p class="step2 help-2" style="top: 48px; left: 60px" > 
      <label class="checkboxButtons">
            <span class="icon" ></span>
            <span style="padding-right: 25px;top: 5px;position: relative;">Mémoriser votre code
            </span>
      </label>
       <br><br>
      <label class="checkboxButtons">
            <span class="icon" ></span>
            <span style="padding-right: 25px;top: 5px;position: relative;">De code registreren
            </span>
      </label>
      <br><br><br>
      <label class="checkboxButtons">
            <span class="icon" ></span>
            <span style="padding-right: 25px;top: 5px;position: relative;">Record the code
            </span>
      </label>  
    </p>

      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` will fix that issue wrap them in another div container and write this to container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `float`in 2021 it's kinda outdated and it's what caused your problem, I'd suggest using `flexbox` to align your red block and your labels on one line, then replace that `<p>` with a `<div>` that uses `flex-direction : column;` adding spaces using `<br>` is bad practice.

Also I noticed you had inline style in some of your html tags you should put everything in your css file.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 #content {
      background: #fff;
  }
  
 #content .wrapper {
      padding-top: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  
 #content .wrapper {
      padding: 0 0 50px 0;
  }
  
 .wrapper {
      width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: aqua;
      height: 70%;
      display : flex;
 }


#content .backgroundRed {
      width: 200px;
      background-color: red;
      height: 250px;
  }
  
  .step2 {
  display : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items : flex-start;
  margin-left : 40px;
  }
  
   #content .checkboxButtons {
      position: relative;
      background-color: yellow;
      margin-bottom : 15px;
}


.checkboxButtons .icon {
      top: -8px;
      left: -20px;
      position: absolute;
      height: 27px;
      width: 25px;
      background: url("https://zupimages.net/up/21/27/ijsz.png") -60px -911px no-repeat;
}

.checkboxButtons .label-text {
padding : 5px 25px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="backgroundRed">     
      </div>
      <div class="step2 help-2" > 
      <label class="checkboxButtons">
            <span class="icon" ></span>
            <span class="label-text">Mémoriser votre code
            </span>
      </label>
      <label class="checkboxButtons">
            <span class="icon" ></span>
            <span class="label-text">De code registreren
            </span>
      </label>
      <label class="checkboxButtons">
            <span class="icon" ></span>
            <span class="label-text">Record the code
            </span>
      </label>  
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Xanthous for your explanations. I will follow your advice.